# Instagram API on other users

Tags: instagram-api

I am new to instagram api usage but this website really thrills me: 
https://web.stagram.com/
How can this website access all the users profile details (of course only when they are public but still) ?!

Answer (score 0):

They are most likely using the official Instagram [API](https://www.instagram.com/developer/) along with some other logic to find the most popular users and display their profile.

They could also be using the unofficial API (reverse engineered) to have untethered access to instagram.